# How to implement custom paging in ASP.NET Gridview that has Command Buttons in VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, gridview

I am currently trying to implement a gridview with custom paging. I've gotten this to work by following the tutorial on ASP Snippets, located here:
http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/ASPNet-GridView-Custom-Paging-with-PageSize-Change-Dropdown.aspx

This work well. However, I run into an issue. My gridview has template controls in it, which run code when used. For example, I have a button that, when clicked, replaces the cell contents with two different buttons. When I use the pagination technique given above, clicking on any template control (causing postback), erases my gridview. I realize that this is because I have to recreate the gridview on every postback because of the way the pagination is set up. However, when I recreate the gridview, the effects of my button are gone because it has been recreated. I'm not sure how to escape this..

Does anyone have any ideas?

For a specific pointed question,

I am looking to create a gridview with custom pagination that will allow for template controls and extended functionality.

Thank you

Generic information:

IDE: Visual Studio 2012

Language: VB.NET, ASP.NET

Database: SQL SERVER 2008 R2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue by programmatic ally resetting the states of my controls to match what they were before post-back.

I haven't had any issues since setting that up.